# Is it possible to rename a file in CodeBlocks?

Tags: codeblocks

Is there a "rename file" option in codeblocks, instead of renaming it through Explorer?
I tried right-clicking the tab, but there didn't seem to be one.

Answer (score 52):

Make sure the file you're renaming isn't open in codeblocks. Under Projects->Workspace, right-click on the file to popup the context menu. From there click "Rename file...":

[image]

Comment: I had to google for this. This makes no sense. You can't rename a file because it's open???? WHAT???

Comment: @AntonioCS It's likely because codeblock has a lock on the opened file that prevents the rename. They could have designed it better to handle this but they didn't unfortunately.

Comment: Like any other IDE? Netbeans, eclipse etc... I just get confused on why people say this is a good c++ IDE when it fails at the most basic things...

Comment: Codeblocks is almost twice as fast as eclipse and netbeans. Eclipse is a nightmare to configure and writing C++ on something that runs on JVM is hideous. Codelite is an alternative, heck even VIM is an alternative, eclipse is not.

Comment: Less is more because CodeBlocks isn't bogged down by a buttload of extra features and tons of overhead. Personally it's my favorite C++ IDE even though I program specifically for Windows. I still prefer it over VS.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the file you're renaming is in front of you. Under Projects->Choose the file->Properties->Change the title.
[Inside Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YJ1L.png)

Comment: The dialog box that you indicate in the link, allows you to rename the name of the project (title), not the name of a header or source file